# YouTube API Playlists in Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, youtube, youtube-api

So I've been trying to put a YouTube playlist into my app for days now, and I can't seem to figure it out. I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-youtube-api-example-channels/), but the problem is my app is in fragments because of the tab view, like this:

```js
public class FragmentTab2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Get the view from fragmenttab1.xml
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab2, container, false);
    }

}
```

How would I do to have the code below, provided by the tutorial, to work on my fragment?

```js
public class TruitonYouTubeAPIActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private YouTubePlayer YPlayer;
    private static final String YoutubeDeveloperKey = "AIzaSyDhEeq_FYAdCzMMSigmMcRwF_nQEhUXS-0";
    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_you_tube_api);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(YoutubeDeveloperKey, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.you_tube_api, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format(
                    "There was an error initializing the YouTubePlayer",
                    errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(YoutubeDeveloperKey, this);
        }
    }

    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
                                        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        YPlayer = player;
 /*
 * Now that this variable YPlayer is global you can access it
 * throughout the activity, and perform all the player actions like
 * play, pause and seeking to a position by code.
 */
        if (!wasRestored) {
            YPlayer.cueVideo("2zNSgSzhBfM");
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.